# Panoramic view in windows mobile (silverlight 4)

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

I was watching MIX session. Presenter there was refering "Panoramic experience" in windows phone. Is a ready-to-use control available anywhere or even beter in silverlight 4 itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a control specifically to do this.  Its not really that hard to achieve with a few visual states and some gesture triggers.  Here is one article describing how it might be done:- [Panoramic Navigation on Windows Phone 7 with No Code!](http://www.innovativesingapore.com/2010/03/panoramic-navigation-on-windows-phone-7-with-no-code/)

If I recall correctly I thought one of the Mix sessions did actually describe in detail how to do this.

Comment: Microsoft's Peter Torr hinted that they intend release something like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Oliver is correct.

Announced with the release of the RTM tools. More details here on the official Panorama and Pivot controls..

[Windows Phone 7 Developer Tools Released - ScottGu's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/16/windows-phone-7-developer-tools-released.aspx)